# Closed Form Solution for a Recurrence Relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

We start out with: $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 7, a_0 = 2$. Is the following valid?

$$a_{n-1} = 3(3a_{n-2}-7)-7 \\ a_{n-1} = 3^2a_{n-2}-(3\cdot-7) - 7 \\ \vdots \\ a_k = 3^ka_{n-k} -(3^{k-1}\cdot-7) \cdots -7\\ \text{Let $k = n$} \\ a_n = 3^ka_0 - (3^{n-1}\cdot-7)-\cdots-7$$

I don't know where to go from here. I would I make a closed form out of this?

Comment: It's not explicitly stated but suggested in your answer to the question, is $a_0=2$?

Comment: Yes! My mistake. I added it in.

Comment: An alternative way to find the closed form expression for $a_n$ is to set $b_n = a_n -\frac{7}{2}$ and observe that $b_n = 3 b_{n-1}$, which implies $b_n = 3^{n}b_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Greg Martin has already pointed out, your closed form cannot be right, because it doesn’t satisfy the recurrence. You could also see whether it generates the right values for $a_1,a_2$, and $a_3$, say, and find that it doesn’t.

There is a slightly better way to organize this sort of ‘unwinding’ of a simple recurrence, but make sure that you do the algebra correctly:

$$\begin{align*}
a_n&=3a_{n-1}-7\\
&=3(3a_{n-2}-7)-7\\
&=3^2a_{n-2}-3\cdot7-7\\
&=3^2(3a_{n-3}-7)-3\cdot7-7\\
&=3^3a_{n-3}-3^2\cdot7-3\cdot7-7\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=3^ka_{n-k}-7\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}3^i\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=3^na_0-7\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i\\
&=2\cdot3^n-7\cdot\frac{3^n-1}{3-1}\\
&=2\cdot3^n-\frac{7\cdot3^n-7}2\\
&=\frac12(7-3\cdot3^n)\\
&=\frac12(7-3^{n+1})
\end{align*}$$

Note that it’s generally best not to do too much simplification at each stage: too much simplification tends to obscure the pattern. And when you’re done, you should always check to be sure that your closed form satisfies the recurrence:

$$3\left(\frac12(7-3^n)\right)-7=\frac32\cdot7-\frac12\cdot3^{n+1}-7=\frac12(3^{n+1}-7)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you! Very clear! One question though. You solve the sum by using the fact that the sum is geometric, why is it $3^n$ instead of $3^{n-1}$? Is that just because of definition for the formula to solve geometric sums? I know its $\frac{ar^n - 1}{r-1}$

Comment: My mistake, it was supposed to say $3^{n-1}$.

Comment: @E__: Yes, it’s just the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series. $$\sum_{i=0}^{\color{red}n}r^i=\frac{r^{\color{red}{n+1}}-1}{r-1}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you! I had my formula to $r^n$. That really clears the air.

Comment: @E__: Excellent; you’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi professor Scott, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841574/prove-that-the-integer-numbers-has-the-completness-property), please?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct as written. Notice that (the left-hand side of the first line should be $a_n$, and) the right-hand side equals $3\cdot 3a_{n-2} - 3\cdot 7 - 7$. In particular, we subtract $3\cdot7+7$, not just $7+7$. So the $-7n$ in the last line won't be correct.

In general, you don't even have to know whether your algebraic steps were correct or not to test the final answer! Try plugging in the proposed formula $a_n = 2\cdot 3^n - 7n$ to the recurrence: the result is
$$
2\cdot 3^n - 7n = 3(2\cdot 3^{n-1} - 7(n-1)) - 7 = 2\cdot 3^n - 21(n-1) - 7 = 2\cdot 3^n - 21n + 14,
$$
which is incorrect, revealing that something went wrong.

Comment: I corrected my mistake. Thank you! Is there a way I can solve this in it's current form to get to a closed form?